How do I make GitHub auth work on my SST API?
My SST app should offer multiple OAuth2/OIDC logins. I can make Google and GitHub work on the front end and now I'm trying to secure the APIs. I can do that for Google using JWT, and I'm prepared to have a different set of APIs for each provider, even though it would be a bit messy. What I'm stuck with is GitHub cos it doesn't seem to return a JWT.
Google does return a JWT so I decoded it with jwt.io to get the "iss" and "aud" fields:
  const api = new Api(stack, "Api", {
    authorizers: {
      googleAuther: {
        type: "jwt",
        jwt: {
          // These are from the decoded JWT token I get when I log in with google:
          issuer: "https://accounts.google.com",
          audience: "XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com" }
    }},
    routes: {
      "GET  /settings/{user}" : { 
          function: "packages/functions/src/getUser.handler", 
          authorizer: "googleAuther" }
    }
  });

I'm making the session in the style of the api-auth-google example code and I put the provider's name, the raw token and all the user details into the SST session which then goes into the context. Then in one of my components I can call the API:
const session = useAppContext()
t = JSON.parse(session.token).id_token
fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/settings/${userID}`,
      { method: "GET", headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${t}`} })
.then( ...

So, now I'd like it to work with GitHub. It doesn't give me JWTs and I see little point making my own (?). All I can think of is to pass GitHub's token to the API and have it call GitHub with it to see who it is, but that's a pointless round trip every time. With a JWT token the API implementation can check the signature without any round trip.
So what are we supposed to do? Or can GitHub be coerced into returning a JWT token instead of this useless one?
